# Crop a child control to a region in .NET WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, graphics

I am currently designing a user control which will have other controls contained within it. I would like to be able to control the region in which the they are rendered (similar to   `Graphics.SetClip`).

Ideally I would like to beable to have them render to an off screen image which I then present to the user as I choose. The last resort would be to place a panel in my control and then use that as their parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [Control.Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx) property of the child controls.  From the docs:

> The operating system does not display
>   any portion of a window that lies
>   outside of the window region.

Note the region is relative to control on which it is *set*, not your containing control (unlike Graphics.SetClip).

Comment: Works a charm - can't believe I didn't see that there :)