# C# Non-rectangular Button

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, button

I'm trying to come up with a way to make a non-rectangular button in a Windows Form in C#.  I've searched around for this, and there's plenty of tutorials (including on Microsoft's own documentation) on how to make buttons *appearances* non-rectangular, but - and this is critical - none of them do anything about making the *active area* of the button non-rectangular.  If, for example, you make an elliptical button, the corners of the bounding rectangle are still what's used to pick up mouse events such as rollovers and clicks.  This is not acceptable for my needs.  I need to have several oddly-shaped buttons adjacent to eachother, and their bounding rects may overlap, but they should only respond to clicks within the visible part of the button graphic.  I've seen several questions like this for other languages (mostly Objective-C), but none for C#.  Is this even possible with Winforms?

Comment: Is WPF an option for you? That's really easy to achieve in WPF by overriding the `HitTest`-related methods. Winforms is a really old technology and is not intended to be customized that much...

Comment: WinForms is built on top of even older technology (Win32) that handles this easily.

Comment: 1. you can work around this, by hit testing and redirecting the events. 2. you can easily do it with WPF

Comment: Never actually worked with WPF.  Not even really sure where to start with that.  Is this really the only way around this issue?  Seems like it shouldn't be that unusual a request...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Rounded corner container in .net winform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229163/creating-rounded-corner-container-in-net-winform), [Crop a child control to a region in .NET WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1931596)

Comment: I think those might do the trick - to be fair, this one has a name more likely to be found in a search for the subject...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Win32 windows are always rectangular.  However, having "holes" in the window is completely possible if you use [`SetWindowRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145102.aspx).  There are also the ["Layered Window" APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx).

You probably can't do this from pure WinForms, however.  Expect to reach for p/invoke.

---

Looks like you can do it from pure WinForms: Simply set the [`Control.Region`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx) property.

A more complete example is available [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289517.aspx#vbtchshapedwindowsformscontrolsinvisualstudionetanchor4)

Comment: Yeah, but the question was about buttons within a window, not the whole window...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Buttons ARE windows, in native Win32 including WinForms.  (WPF does use windowless controls with cooperative rendering)  `SetWindowRgn` should work on buttons just fine -- use the `Handle` property of the control.

Comment: Okay, but looking at the documentation (I haven't tried this yet - might need some sample code), it looks like the only options are "One Rectangle" or "Multiple Rectangles", which would make it very difficult to design a shape that has diagonals or curves.  You'd pretty much have to use a whole lot of really small rectangles to try and match the shape.  I'm looking for something that would respond to the alpha of the button graphic - which in this case is either fully opaque or fully transparent.  Clicking the transparent areas should not count as a click.  Is this not possible in WinForms?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: The Layered Window APIs use the alpha channel to determine the shape.  `SetWindowRgn` uses the Region API, and yes regions are internally stored as a set of rectangles, but this is to make hit testing efficient.  It's possible to create a region from an arbitrarily complex path.  See http://www.flounder.com/setwindowrgn.htm for an extended example (in C++)

Comment: Wow - it looks like it does what I need but that seems like a whole lot of work - though it's probably less in C#.  Trick is figuring out which bits are relevant and which are just all the extra stuff you need in C++.  Still trying to decide whether switching to WPF might be easier overall.  Might take me a few days to work through all this...

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer.  It may take me a bit before I can get to testing it, but between this and the links in the comments above, I think I know where to go next.  Thanks.